# Unable to set background color of Excel cells conditionally via Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to populate data into Excel sheet using pandas dataframe and Python, using the below snippet but the cells are not getting the appropriate background colors.

```
dfList = []
def color_cells(val):
    print(val,type(val))
    if val < 0:
        return ['background-color: red']
    else:
        return ['background-color: green']

for index in args.indices:
    indexDF = someMethodToPopulateDF()
    dfList.append(indexDF)


finalDF = pd.concat(dfList,axis=1)
finalDF.style.apply(color_cells)
finalDF.to_excel('Comparison.xls', header=True)
```

For more clarity, dfList is a list of dataframes which is getting populated by some method, I am later concatenating this list into a single dataframe. I intend to write this final dataframe to an excel sheet.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to apply the background color elementwise, you should use `applymap`, remove the square braces from the text style *and* reassign the generated `Styler` to a variable that can later produce the desired `xls`. Moreover, you can also use the following [Styler.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Building-Styles-Summary) functions with the `axis` keyword argument to iterate over your data columnwise or rowwise.

- Styler.applymap(func) for elementwise styles
- Styler.apply(func, axis=0) for columnwise styles
- Styler.apply(func, axis=1) for rowwise styles
- Styler.apply(func, axis=None) for tablewise styles

```py
import pandas as pd

def color_cells(val):
    print(val,type(val))
    if val < 0:
        return 'background-color: red'
    else:
        return 'background-color: green'

dfList = []
for i in ['A','B','C']:
    dfList.append(pd.DataFrame({i: [j for j in range(-5,5)]}))

finalDF = pd.concat(dfList, axis=1)
finalDF = finalDF.style.applymap(color_cells)
finalDF.to_excel('Comparison.xls', header=True)
```

[image: excel_output]